# Predicting target location given cursor speed and direction

Tags: algorithms, hci

Do you guys know of any method or algorithm you are able to predict where a user is moving their cursor given its speed and bearing?

I'm trying to predict if and when users are moving their mouse to a certain part of the screen (address bar location).

Could I exploit Fitts's Law in this regard?

Comment: Do you have a data set, with ground truth (i.e., mouse movements and the eventual destination)?  Have you tried brainstorming a few simple features and trying some machine learning?

Comment: "Do you have a data set, with ground truth"

Yes, so far I am able to determine previous mouse positions, and then can calculate its speed and direction.  I also know the exact location of the area that I am interested in.

What suggestions would you have for machine learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fitts's law gives you a guess for the length of the movement (in terms of screen distance), and so gives you a rough spot where the user is aiming. Make a list of "points of interest" where the user is likely to click (a priori), and then put together a score which takes into account both the probability that the movement ends at the point, and its prominence. Pick the point with maximal score.

Machine learning has been used to derive the parameters for Fitts's law, and I'm not sure anything more is needed here apart from some UI experiments.

Comment: By a guess for length, do you mean a guess for time, from which I can derive distance?

Comment: @hoshi Not necessarily. You could also model acceleration and deceleration. The end result of your model would be an estimate of the distance.

Comment: Could you explain to me how I would be able to estimate Distance using the fitt's law formula?  Would I take the equation and solve for Distance?

Comment: @hoshi Sounds right, although I'm not an expert on Fitts' law.

Comment: Except how would I do that when distance is on both sides of the equasion?  Would distance in the Log term be a constant? while the distance on the left hand side(a factor of time) be our variable?  Also do you know what the "a" term represents? how long the mouse takes to stop?

Comment: @hoshi I recommend finding a good and clear description of Fitts' law, or alternatively asking a concrete question here. Perhaps Fitts' law doesn't answer your question after all, or perhaps you need some non-trivial derivation to connect your problem to the question Fitts was trying to answer.